# why do parenthesis preserve this when called in same statement

Tags: javascript, function, this, evaluation, parentheses

Consider the following variables:

```
var obj = {
    value    : 'from object',
    getValue : function() { return this.value; }
};

var value = 'from global';
```

Now, `obj.getValue()` evaluates to `'from object'`.  And if I get a reference to just the getValue function and call it:

```
var f = obj.getValue;
f();
```

f evaluates to `'from global'`.

My question is why does `(obj.getValue)();` return `'from object'`?

I would have thought that the first set of parenthesis would evaluate to a plain reference to the getValue function and then when calling that result, `this` would be the global context.  Why does the interpreter assume this is a call on the object?

Answer (score 1):

When you call `var f = obj.getValue();`, you are running the `getValue` method from the object. When you call `var f = obj.getValue;`, you are reassigning the function to `f`, and then when you call `f`, it has no ties to `obj`, it is simply called as a global function.

Comment: I got that.  My question is why does `(obj.getValue)()` keep the obj scope?

Comment: The question is why `(obj.getValue)()` acts as `obj.getValue()`, while lexically it looks more like `f = obj.getValue; f()`